# Compiling: undefined reference to

Tags: c, makefile, linker, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I'm struggling with compiling multiple files into a common program. I'm getting an error:

> undefined reference to 'pi'

Here's the skeleton of my code and Makefile. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

File: calcPi.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "pi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    long iterations = 1000000;
    int policy = 2;
    int numChildren = 3;
    pi(iterations, policy, numChildren);
    return 0;
}
```

File: pi.h

```
void pi(long iterations, int policy, int numChildren);
```

File: pi.c

```
#include "pi.h"

void pi(long iterations, int policy, int numChildren) {
    //lots of code here
}
```

I'm compiling this using a Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c -g -Wall -Wextra
LFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra

all: calcPi pi

calcPi: calcPi.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -lm

pi: pi.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -lm

calcPi.o: calcPi.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

pi.o: pi.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

clean:
    rm -f pi calcPi
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *~
```

EDIT: In response to the request for the entire error message:

In function 'main'"
calcPi.c:55: undefined reference to 'pi'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [calcPi.o] error 1

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete console output from your build process (especially the line where things are being linked).

Comment: Your `CFLAGS` should not contain `-c` IIRC. and you probably want to link all your object files `calcPi.o` and `pi.o` together (unless you have two different `main`-s in them...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I'd think `-c` would be appropriate if you want to separate the compilation and linking phases, which appears to be the case here.

Comment: Run `make -p`; it will shows you the default `COMPILE.c` and the rule using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, is **pi** really supposed to be a separate application?

You're referring the pi() function from **calcPi**, but it's only been compiled into **pi.o**, so you need to add it as a dependency.

What I think you want to do, is to create **calcPi** using the **calcPi.o** and **pi.o** object files.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c -g -Wall -Wextra
LFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra

all: calcPi

calcPi: calcPi.o pi.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -lm

calcPi.o: calcPi.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

pi.o: pi.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

clean:
    rm -f calc
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *~
```

Comment: Might want to remove `pi` from `all` as well.

Comment: That's it. Thanks! That helps me to understand this process a bit better.